# Referencing node attributes from Chef Audit Control Group

Tags: chef-infra, audit

I'm trying to find out if there is a way to reference my node attributes in a Chef Control Group when running in audit mode. As an example, I have a particular recipe that references an attribute for my http(s) proxy and I need to make sure the proxy server is set correctly via my audit.

So, I want to check the contents of my proxy config file and make sure it has the appropriate proxy server in the file. But I currently can't verify this because the audit mode doesn't seem to recognize when I reference:

```
node['default']['proxy_server']
```

or

```
"#{node['default']['proxy_server']}"
```

Is it just not possible to reference attributes in audit mode? Or is there just a super-secret syntax that I am unaware of? Thanks!!

Comment: Which audit mode do you mean, the older "audit mode" or the newer audit cookbook?

Comment: Using the old audit mode.
`'Chef::Config[:audit_mode] = :audit_only`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to cram node attrs in to global variables or similar and access them from inside the audit controls. Not recommended though since 1) that kind of defeats the point of testing if you are using the same parameters for both the code and the test and 2) it isn't possible with newer InSpec-based tools like the audit cookbook or Compliance.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding correctly....unless I essentially hard-code the values into variables inside the recipe, it can't really be done?

Comment: Again, it can be done, but it shouldn't be. The whole point of tests is to compare against known output values. If you have some code that does `x = y` and then test it by checking `x == y`, you haven't actually checked that `x` has the correct value overall.

Comment: Do you know if there is a more robust way to run audits for things like hardening compliance? One situation, as an example, is that the grub config file has to have certain permissions...but the path/name of the config file is different between AmazonLinux and RHEL...which is why I was hoping to use the attributes to pass the value of the path/filename.

Comment: I was trying to follow an example from [Chef.io](https://docs.chef.io/dsl_recipe.html#id1) that showed a control block being preceded by setting a variable based on an attribute:  
`memory_mb = node['memory']['total'].gsub(/kB$/i, '').to_i / 1024  
control 'minimum memory check' do  
  it 'should be at least 400MB free' do  
    expect(memory_mb).to be >= 400  
  end  
end`

Comment: You would generally put the OS check in the control itself, though the specifics vary between Serverspec (what you are using) and InSpec (what all new things use).